# Weird behaviour of PagerSlidingTabStrip inside NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, fragmentpageradapter, pagerslidingtabstrip

When the activity starts it loads a `NavigationDrawer` and inside there are 3 sections. 1st has a RecyclerView which works correctly. 2nd has a `PagerSlidingTabStrip` which has problems. 3rd has some code which changes PreferenceManager and works good.

Now the problem is that the `getItem()` method of `CustomPagerAdapter` is called only once ie. only the first time when I click User section from `NavigationDrawer` but after navigating when i try to open it again `getItem()` isn't called so nothing is initialized inside the `ViewPager`.

Then I've to reopen the app and `PagerSlidingTabStrip` will work one time.

Please guide me. What could be the problem?

**UPDATE:**
I did some tests and found that `getItem()` of `FragmentPagerAdapter` is called only once for the first time I launch section 2 then when I try to launch it again it's not called. Why so?

**NavigationDrawer sections:**

```
    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        switch(position) {
            case 0: //Events
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                        EventsRecyclerViewFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();
                break;

            case 1: //User
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                        UserFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();
                break;

            case 2: //Logout
                prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                if(prefs.getBoolean(KEY_LOGIN, false)) {
                    prefs.edit().remove(KEY_LOGIN).apply();
                    prefs.edit().remove(KEY_USERNAME).apply();
                    prefs.edit().remove(KEY_PASSWORD).apply();
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Customs.mToast(getBaseContext(), "Logged-out");
                }
                break;
        }
}
```

**The 2nd section - UserFragment:**

```
static class UserFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public static UserFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            UserFragment fragment = new UserFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user, container, false);
            context = view.getContext();
            prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(view.getContext());
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getFragmentManager(),context));

            PagerSlidingTabStrip pagerSlidingTabStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip)view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
            pagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(mViewPager);
        }
    }
```

**FragmentPagerAdapter - CustomAdapter:**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private Context context;
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username",
            KEY_PASSWORD = "password", KEY_LOGIN = "loggedin";

    public CustomAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        if(!prefs.getBoolean(KEY_LOGIN, false)) {
            prefs.edit().remove(KEY_USERNAME).apply();
            prefs.edit().remove(KEY_PASSWORD).apply();
            String[] pageTitle = {"Login", "Register"};
            return pageTitle[position];
        }
        String[] pageTitle = {"Update", "Register"};
        return pageTitle[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                if(!prefs.getBoolean(KEY_LOGIN, false)) {
                    prefs.edit().remove(KEY_USERNAME).apply();
                    prefs.edit().remove(KEY_PASSWORD).apply();
                    return LoginFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
                }
                else {
                    return UpdateFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
                }

            case 1:
                return RegisterFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        //container.removeView((View) object);
        FragmentManager manager = ((Fragment)object).getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
        trans.remove((Fragment)object);
        trans.commit();
    }
}
```

**NavigationDrawer:**

[image: NavigationDrawer]

**1st time opened User from NavigaiontDrawer:**

[image: 1st time opened User from NavigaiontDrawer]

**2nd time opened User from NavigaiontDrawer:**

[image: 2nd time opened User from NavigaiontDrawer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem is solved. I just changed from `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

The problem with `FragmentPagerAdapter` was that it creates `Fragments` only once and the next time it restores it. That should have worked fine but again I've a layer of `NavigationDrawer` over the `Pager` so when I changed the the sections from NavigationDrawer something gets messed up and the FragmentPagerAdapter neither fetches the fragments nor does it create new ones.

Comment: If anyone can explain this behaviour please do it, I'm very curious to know.